# fwrite writes out bytes, not the actual integer

Tags: c, file-io

I'm completing an assignment wherein I need to output data like this:

```
255 0 0 255 0 0 255 0 0
255 0 0 255 0 0 255 0 0
255 0 0 255 0 0 255 0 0
```

What came to mind first was to output a pixel at a time but my professor wants me to output it all at once by using fwrite.

Every time I use fwrite I end up having my output as actual bytes, not integers.

How can I fix this?

```
int rows = 3;
int cols = 3;
int imgsize = (3 * rows * cols);
unsigned char *img = malloc(imgsize);
int ri = 0;
int ci = 0;

for (ri = 0; ri < rows; ri++) {
     for (ci = 0; ci < cols; ci++) {
         *img = 255;
         *(img + 1) = 0;
         *(img + 2) = 0;
         img += 3;
     }
 }

 FILE *fp = fopen("output", "w");
 fwrite(img, 1, imgsize, fp);
 fclose(fp);
```

Comment: how does the output look like ?

Comment: You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code, because you change the pointer `img` inside the loops, so when the loops are done you no longer have the original pointer. That means you are writing `imgsize` bytes of indeterminate (seemingly random) *binary* data.

Comment: Either you misunderstand your assignment, or whoever wrote your assignment doesn't understand C. `fwrite` outputs bytes, that's what it's *for*. You don't get to "fix" that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what `fwrite` does. If you want *formatted output* then you can use the `printf` function.

For example,

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < imgsize; ++i)
    fprintf(fp, "%d ", img[i]);
```

If you want to insert newlines after a certain number of entries then you can add logic to this loop for that.

NB. As pointed out by Joachim Pileborg, you should modify your `for` loops so that they operate on a different pointer that's copied from `img`. Otherwise you have lost track of where the start of the image's storage actually is.

Comment: Perhaps fprintf() would be more appropriate than printf() for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

fread and fwrite deals with data in Binary format i.e system understandable code.If you use `fwrite` ,then you should use `fread` and vice versa.

To write proper format of data in file, Use `fprintf` and `fscanf` which are deals with data in actual format.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `fwrite` indeed writes "bytes", but that's because all files are just bytes. It's the kind of data that those bytes represent, and how you interpret them, that's important. Bytes can be text, or they can be some sort of binary encoded data.

Notwithstanding the pointer bug that @JoachimPileborg pointed out in the comment, you are indeed writing what looks like a bitmap image to file, one byte per value. Are you sure that's not actually what you're trying to do here? Most image bitmaps are indeed written something like this.

If what you really want is actually a file of text that shows a *representation* of the integers in text form, then indeed, try `fprintf` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can print formatted data into buffer and then output if like binary

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    FILE *out = NULL;
    char buffer[1024];
    int num255, num0;
    int length;

    out = fopen("C:/c/bintxt.txt", "wb");
    if (out == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    num255 = 255;
    num0 = 0;
    sprintf(buffer, "%d %d %d %d %d %d\0", num255, num0, num0, num255, num0, num0);
    length = strlen(buffer);
    fwrite(buffer, 1, length, out);
    fclose(out);
    //_getch();
}
```